# sass variables not shared across imports

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have the following setup for my sass files:

base.scss

```
@import "colors";
@import "forms";
```

_colors.scss

```
$gray: #ccc;
```

_forms.scss

```
form {
    background: $gray;
}
```

When I run `grunt sass` to build the css I get the following error:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$gray".
        on line xx of sass/_forms.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Comment: Show us your Gruntfile please.

Comment: It occurred to me that might be the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my sass grunt task, I was processing the entire directory instead of just the `base.scss`.

Here is the fix for any future people having the same issue:

You want to watch all files for changes.

```
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: './sass/**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']
        }
    }
```

You want to only process `base.scss` since it includes all the other `_foo.scss` files (these will get processed just by watching the base file.

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './sass',
                src: ['base.scss'],
                dest: './public/css',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass), it was [updated](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/commit/26b1e3081f63b6ecc56db94046ee506109505f9a) to ignore "_" sass files. From its readme:

> Note: Files that begin with "_" are ignored even if they match the globbing pattern. This is done to match the expected [Sass partial behaviour](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).

[grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) introduced the same in release v0.6.0 (See their [release history](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#release-history)).

Both these plugins were updated after you asked your question.

So, your grunt task can now remain what it was originally, which will enable you to have multiple "base" files - independent sass files which are compiled separately, while partials won't be compiled.